# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. x was 0x20B4112

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

float str_to_float(char x[]) {
    int j;
    float val1 = x[0] - '0';
    float val2=0,factor=1;
 
    for (int i = 1; x[i] != '.'; i++) {
        val1 = (val1 * 10) + (x[i] - '0'); 
        j = i;
    }
    for (int k = j + 2; k != '\0'; k++) {
        **val2 = val2 + (x[k] - '0')*factor;**
        factor /= 10;
    }
    return val1+val2;
    }

int main() {
    char x[1000];
    cin.getline(x, 1000);
    cout<<str_to_float(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This function should return a float value of a string containing a float number.
An error occur at the line in bold (in the second for loop) while debugging "read access violation"

Comment: `k != '\0'` You don't really want to compare an index into the array with a char value from the array.

Comment: What value will `j` have when `x[1]` is a decimal point (for example, if the user enters `1.23`)?

Comment: What do you think the first loop will do if the string does not contain a decimal point at all?   For example `"2"`.

Comment: As a matter of style, you don’t need `i` and `k`. Just use `j` as the loop control variable in both loops. That way you don’t need to copy the values around: `for (j = 1; x[j] != ‘.’; ++j)`, then between the two loops increment `j` past the decimal point with `++j;` then run the second loop `for ( ; x[j] !=  ‘\0’; ++j)`.

Comment: Also, those repeated divisions by 10 introduce roundoff errors that accumulate. You’ll get a more accurate result if you just accumulate the digits to the right of the decimal point as an integral value, just like the first loop, then divide by `std::pow(10, n)`, where `n` is the number of digits that you saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. For the second loop, change the condition to `x[k] != '\0'`.
2. The variable `factor` should be initialised to `0.1`.

Also, to avoid some runtime errors (for example, in the case of 0.908), start the first loop from index `0`, so that variable `j` has a valid value before starting the second loop.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

double str_to_double(char x[]) {
    
    int j;
    double val1 = 0, val2 = 0.0, factor = 0.1;
    
    for (int i = 0; x[i] != '.'; i++) {
        val1 = (val1 * 10) + (x[i] - '0'); 
        j = i;
    }
    for (int k = j + 2; x[k] != '\0'; k++) {
        val2 = val2 + (x[k] - '0')*factor;
        factor /= 10;
    }
    return val1+val2;
}

int main() {
    char x[1000];
    std::cin.getline(x, 1000);
    std::cout<<std::setprecision(15)<<str_to_double(x);
    return 0;
}
```

**Test Cases:**

1. Test Case 1: Input: `34.908`, Output: `34.908`
2. Test Case 2: Input: `0.908`, Output: `0.908`
3. Test Case 3: Input: `000006795.989090877700000`, Output: `6795.9890908777`

**PS:** For large values of `float` and `double`, there may be a precision loss. Read this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).